# Ionic 5 back button not working in signed apk

Tags: javascript, android, capacitor, ionic5

In my ionic android app, i am using android hardware back button to navigate previous page and at last to exit app but it is not working at all, even i tried to check is there click event is working or not but there is no luck.
I had gone through many solutions but it was for ionic 3 and 4 which is also not working solution.
Please suggest if you have any solution for this issue

here is my code:
app.component.ts file

```js
import { Component, QueryList, ViewChild, ViewChildren } from '@angular/core';

import { AlertController, IonRouterOutlet, Platform } from '@ionic/angular';
import { SplashScreen } from '@ionic-native/splash-screen/ngx';
import { StatusBar } from '@ionic-native/status-bar/ngx';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './services/auth.service';
import { CommonService } from './services/common.service';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';
import {Location} from '@angular/common';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: 'app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  displayUserData: any;
  fname: string;
  lname: string;
  skill: string;
  photo: string;
  assetURL: string;
  role_id: number;
  interval: any;
  @ViewChildren(IonRouterOutlet) routerOutlets: QueryList < IonRouterOutlet > ;
  lastTimeBackPress = 0;
  timePeriodToExit = 2000;
  notification_count: any;
  constructor(
    private platform: Platform,
    private splashScreen: SplashScreen,
    private router: Router,
    private statusBar: StatusBar,
    private authService: AuthService,
    private commonService: CommonService,
    public alertController: AlertController,
    private location: Location,
    private activeRoute: ActivatedRoute,
  ) {
    this.assetURL = environment.assetsUrl;
    this.initializeApp();
    this.loadData();
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      this.loadData();
    }, 3000);
  }
  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.interval) {
      clearInterval(this.interval);
    }
  }
  initializeApp() {
    this.platform.ready().then(() => {
      this.statusBar.styleDefault();
      this.splashScreen.hide();
      // this.router.navigateByUrl('splash')
      this.backButtonEvent();
    });
  }
  logout(){
    // this.authService.logout();
    
    this.LogoutConfirm();
  }
  async LogoutConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Do you want to sign out?',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'No',
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'secondary',
        handler: (blah) => {}
      }, {
        text: 'Yes',
        handler: () => {
          this.authService.logout();
        }
      }]
    });
    await alert.present();
   
  }
  loadData(){
    this.authService.userData.subscribe((res: any)=>{
      this.displayUserData = res;
      if(this.displayUserData){
        this.getDetails(this.displayUserData.token);
        this.getOtherData(this.displayUserData.token);
      }
    }) 
  }
  getDetails(token){
      this.commonService.getDetails(token).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        if(res.status == 'success'){
          const data = res.data;
          if(data){
            this.fname = data.fname;
            this.lname = data.lname;
            this.skill = this.displayUserData.role == 2 ? 'Makeup Designer' : data.skill;
            this.photo = data.photo;
            this.role_id = data.role_id
          }
        }else{
          // this.toastService.presentToast(res.message, 'top');
        }
      }, (error: any) => {  }
    )
  }
  getOtherData(token){
    this.commonService.getOtherData(token).subscribe((res:any)=>{
        if(res.status == 'success'){
          this.commonService.changeNotifyCount(res.data.notification_count);
        }else{ }
      }, (error: any) => { console.log(error) }
    )
  }
  backButtonEvent() {
    this.platform.backButton.subscribeWithPriority(0, () => {
      console.log(this.router.url);
      this.routerOutlets.forEach(async(outlet: IonRouterOutlet) => {
        if (this.router.url != '/index/home') {
          await this.router.navigate(['/index/home']);
        } else if (this.router.url === '/index/home') {
          if (new Date().getTime() - this.lastTimeBackPress >= this.timePeriodToExit) {
            this.lastTimeBackPress = new Date().getTime();
            this.presentAlertConfirm();
          } else {
            navigator['app'].exitApp();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }
  
  async presentAlertConfirm() {
    const alert = await this.alertController.create({
      message: 'Do you want to exit the app?',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'Cancel',
        role: 'cancel',
        cssClass: 'secondary',
        handler: (blah) => {}
      }, {
        text: 'Exit',
        handler: () => {
          navigator['app'].exitApp();
        }
      }]
    });
  
    await alert.present();
  }
}
```